# Migration with dotnet ef error: Unable to create an object of type 'MyClass'

Tags: c#, database-migration

I'm trying to have a migration using dotnet ef migrations add MyMigration, but shell returns an error: Unable to create an object of type 'AuthDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728.

This is my AuthDbContext.cs file:

```
using Auth.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Auth.Data
{
public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    private readonly string connStr;

    //public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options) : base(options)  //string connStr)
    {
        //this.connStr = connStr;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // string connStr = "";
        // connStr = "";
        // if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        // {
        //    optionsBuilder
        //        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
        //        .UseSqlServer(connStr);
        // }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("auth");
        //modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(p => new { p.User_id });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    


 }
}
```

Can somebody help me to understand? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add this line

```
base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
```

EF Core can't finish context instantiating.

Comment: Thanks. Can you specify exactly where? I’m sorry but i’m  so new on it